# Python: How to replace N random string occurrences in text?

Tags: python

Say that I have 10 different tokens, "(TOKEN)" in a string. How do I replace 2 of those tokens, chosen at random, with some other string, leaving the other tokens intact?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have 10 instances of the same string (say, "foo") in the string?  Or, that you have 10 individuall unique strings in the string?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import random
>>> text = '(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)'
>>> token = '(TOKEN)'
>>> replace = 'foo'
>>> num_replacements = 2
>>> num_tokens = text.count(token) #10 in this case
>>> points = [0] + sorted(random.sample(range(1,num_tokens+1),num_replacements)) + [num_tokens+1]
>>> replace.join(token.join(text.split(token)[i:j]) for i,j in zip(points,points[1:]))
'(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__foo__(TOKEN)__foo__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)__(TOKEN)'
```

In function form:

```
>>> def random_replace(text, token, replace, num_replacements):
        num_tokens = text.count(token)
        points = [0] + sorted(random.sample(range(1,num_tokens+1),num_replacements)) + [num_tokens+1]
        return replace.join(token.join(text.split(token)[i:j]) for i,j in zip(points,points[1:]))

>>> random_replace('....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....','(TOKEN)','FOO',2)
'....FOO....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....(TOKEN)....FOO....'
```

Test:

```
>>> for i in range(0,9):
        print random_replace('....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....','(0)','(%d)'%i,i)


....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....
....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(1)....(0)....(0)....(0)....
....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(0)....(2)....(2)....(0)....
....(3)....(0)....(0)....(3)....(0)....(3)....(0)....(0)....
....(4)....(4)....(0)....(0)....(4)....(4)....(0)....(0)....
....(0)....(5)....(5)....(5)....(5)....(0)....(0)....(5)....
....(6)....(6)....(6)....(0)....(6)....(0)....(6)....(6)....
....(7)....(7)....(7)....(7)....(7)....(7)....(0)....(7)....
....(8)....(8)....(8)....(8)....(8)....(8)....(8)....(8)....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly two, then:

1. Detect the tokens (keep some links to them, like index into the string)
2. Choose two at random (`random.choice`)
3. Replace them

Comment: Maybe you could expand on the 3rd step just a little more for the OP? Im guessing they might be just as interested in how to specifically replace at these indexes. I feel the 3rd step is oversimplified?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do, exactly?  A good answer will depend on that...

That said, a brute-force solution that comes to mind is to:

1. Store the 10 tokens in an array, such that tokens[0] is the first token, tokens[1] is the second, ... and so on
2. Create a dictionary to associate each unique "(TOKEN)" with two numbers: start_idx, end_idx
3. Write a little parser that walks through your string and looks for each of the 10 tokens.  Whenever one is found, record the start/end indexes (as start_idx, end_idx) in the string where that token occurs.
4. Once done parsing, generate a random number in the range [0,9].  Lets call this **R**
5. Now, your random "(TOKEN)" is tokens[**R**];
6. Use the dictionary in step (3) to find the start_idx, end_idx values in the string; replace the text there with "some other string"

Comment: I think you did misinterpret the intentions of the OP. He is saying he has a string that has, say, 10 occurrences of "TOKEN" and he only wants to randomly replace 2 of them. What you are talking about is having 10 different tokens I think, and returning actual tokens

Comment: Gah, please read again.  I inadvertently submitted too early.

Comment: Err, yes, you may be right - that he has 10 instances of the same string.  Not that each token is unique.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in code:

```
import random

s = "(TOKEN)test(TOKEN)fgsfds(TOKEN)qwerty(TOKEN)42(TOKEN)(TOKEN)ttt"
replace_from = "(TOKEN)"
replace_to = "[REPLACED]"
amount_to_replace = 2

def random_replace(s, replace_from, replace_to, amount_to_replace):
    parts = s.split(replace_from)
    indices = random.sample(xrange(len(parts) - 1), amount_to_replace)

    replaced_s_parts = list()

    for i in xrange(len(parts)):
        replaced_s_parts.append(parts[i])
        if i < len(parts) - 1:
            if i in indices:
                replaced_s_parts.append(replace_to)
            else:
                replaced_s_parts.append(replace_from)

    return "".join(replaced_s_parts)

#TEST

for i in xrange(5):
    print random_replace(s, replace_from, replace_to, 2)
```

Explanation:

1. Splits string into several parts using `replace_from`
2. Chooses indexes of tokens to replace using `random.sample`. This returned list contains unique numbers
3. Build a list for string reconstruction, replacing tokens with generated index by `replace_to`.
4. Concatenate all list elements into single string

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
import random

def replace_random(tokens, eqv, n):
    random_tokens = eqv.keys()
    random.shuffle(random_tokens)
    for i in xrange(n):
        t = random_tokens[i]
        tokens = tokens.replace(t, eqv[t])
    return tokens
```

Assuming that a string with tokens exists, and a suitable equivalence table can be constructed with a replacement for each token:

```
tokens = '(TOKEN1) (TOKEN2) (TOKEN3) (TOKEN4) (TOKEN5) (TOKEN6) (TOKEN7) (TOKEN8) (TOKEN9) (TOKEN10)'

equivalences = {
    '(TOKEN1)' : 'REPLACEMENT1',
    '(TOKEN2)' : 'REPLACEMENT2',
    '(TOKEN3)' : 'REPLACEMENT3',
    '(TOKEN4)' : 'REPLACEMENT4',
    '(TOKEN5)' : 'REPLACEMENT5',
    '(TOKEN6)' : 'REPLACEMENT6',
    '(TOKEN7)' : 'REPLACEMENT7',
    '(TOKEN8)' : 'REPLACEMENT8',
    '(TOKEN9)' : 'REPLACEMENT9',
    '(TOKEN10)' : 'REPLACEMENT10'
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
replace_random(tokens, equivalences, 2)
> '(TOKEN1) REPLACEMENT2 (TOKEN3) (TOKEN4) (TOKEN5) (TOKEN6) (TOKEN7) (TOKEN8) REPLACEMENT9 (TOKEN10)'
```

Comment: This is similar to the other answer that I think took the misunderstood approach of replacing different tokens. I really think the OP means he has say 10 "token" occurances in a large string and he wants to randomly replace only two with something else. Not randomly select replacements on varying patterns

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.  My approach would be to write a function that takes the original string, the token string, and a function that returns the replacement text for an occurrence of the token in the original:

```
def strByReplacingTokensUsingFunction(original, token, function):
    outputComponents = []
    matchNumber = 0
    unexaminedOffset = 0
    while True:
        matchOffset = original.find(token, unexaminedOffset)
        if matchOffset < 0:
            matchOffset = len(original)
        outputComponents.append(original[unexaminedOffset:matchOffset])
        if matchOffset == len(original):
            break
        unexaminedOffset = matchOffset + len(token)
        replacement = function(original=original, offset=matchOffset, matchNumber=matchNumber, token=token)
        outputComponents.append(replacement)
        matchNumber += 1
    return ''.join(outputComponents)
```

(You could certainly change this to use shorter identifiers.  My style is somewhat more verbose than typical Python style.)

Given that function, it's easy to replace two random occurrences out of ten.  Here's some sample input:

```
sampleInput = 'a(TOKEN)b(TOKEN)c(TOKEN)d(TOKEN)e(TOKEN)f(TOKEN)g(TOKEN)h(TOKEN)i(TOKEN)j(TOKEN)k'
```

The random module has a handy method for picking random items from a population (not picking the same item twice):

```
import random
replacementIndexes = random.sample(range(10), 2)
```

Then we can use the function above to replace the randomly-chosen occurrences:

```
sampleOutput = strByReplacingTokensUsingFunction(sampleInput, '(TOKEN)',
    (lambda matchNumber, token, **keywords:
        'REPLACEMENT' if (matchNumber in replacementIndexes) else token))
print sampleOutput
```

And here's some test output:

```
a(TOKEN)b(TOKEN)cREPLACEMENTd(TOKEN)e(TOKEN)fREPLACEMENTg(TOKEN)h(TOKEN)i(TOKEN)j(TOKEN)k
```

Here's another run:

```
a(TOKEN)bREPLACEMENTc(TOKEN)d(TOKEN)e(TOKEN)f(TOKEN)gREPLACEMENTh(TOKEN)i(TOKEN)j(TOKEN)k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import sample

mystr = 'adad(TOKEN)hgfh(TOKEN)hjgjh(TOKEN)kjhk(TOKEN)jkhjk(TOKEN)utuy(TOKEN)tyuu(TOKEN)tyuy(TOKEN)tyuy(TOKEN)tyuy(TOKEN)'

def replace(mystr, substr, n_repl, replacement='XXXXXXX', tokens=10, index=0):
    choices = sorted(sample(xrange(tokens),n_repl))
    for i in xrange(choices[-1]+1):
        index = mystr.index(substr, index) + 1
        if i in choices:
            mystr = mystr[:index-1] + mystr[index-1:].replace(substr,replacement,1)
    return mystr

print replace(mystr,'(TOKEN)',2)
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `range` instead of `xrange` for python 3 compatibility.